# Haskell-ghci, function toUpper not found?

Tags: function, haskell, ghci, toupper

I'have right now installed the ghci version 8.6.2 and following a tutorial I write:

```
toUpper "something"
```

but ghci compiler prints out:

```
Variable not in scope: toUpper :: [Char] -> t
```

Do I miss some libraries or anything else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [**`toUpper :: Char -> Char`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Char.html#v:toUpper) is not part of the `Prelude`, and thus not imported "implicitly".

You can import it with:

```
import Data.Char(toUpper)
```

or just:

```
import Data.Char
```

to import all functions, datatypes, etc. defined in that module.

Note that it has signature `Char -> Char`, so it only converts a *single* character to its uppercase equivalent.

You thus need to perform a `map`ping:

```
Prelude Data.Char> map toUpper "something"
"SOMETHING"
```